# Date other than current date in gwt date picker

Tags: java, gwt

I have a date field in which user could select dates from the datepicker in a particular date format. In view I am using this snippet which by default show current date selected in the datepicker.

```
this.dateFieldName.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat
                .getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
```

How do i modify the above code in gwt so that when user open the date picker, the default date selected should be 2 months from the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 2 months to java util date and set it to the dateField.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate( currentDate, 2 );
dateFieldName.setValue( currentDate );
```

Hope this would help